# I have made recurrence relation which finds the longest contiguous common string between two strings how can i skip one char in my one of the string

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, recursion, gcc

```
int lcs(int i, int j, int count) 
{ 
    
    if (i == 0 || j == 0) 
        return count; 
        
    if (X[i-1] == Y[j-1]) { 
        count = lcs(i - 1, j - 1, count + 1); 
    } 
      
        count = max(count, max(lcs( i, j - 1, 0), lcs( i - 1, j, 0))); 
    return count; 
}
```

For example:
The X contains AABB and Y contains AACB i want my recurrence relation to skip c to give AAB as the lCCS, this is what i have done so far.

Comment: if you skip C then the common sequence is not contiguous anymore. Do you want to find the longest non-contiguous common subsequence, or what is the rule for C being allowed to be skipped?

Comment: As per the requirement one character in the Y string has been inserted by mistake and needs to be ignored.

Comment: where do you define `X` and `Y`? Please include a [mcve]. You could take a substring of `Y` by removing a character and use a loop to try all substrings you get in that way. Btw that "requirement" isnt clear from the question

Comment: thing is i dont know that character which is inserted by mistake in y :

Comment: X and Y are defined in main 
here it is 
int main() 
{ 
int n,m; 

X = "AABMMMBKKKK"; 
Y = "AACMMMBKKKKK"; 

n=X.size(); 
m=Y.size(); 

cout<<lcs(n,m,0); 

 return 0; 
}

Comment: try all of them

Comment: not helpful , something else please?

Comment: not helpful? Why not? What else do you want to do? If you dont know what character it is you can only try all of them

Comment: i want to skip one char that's all i want to do.

Comment: but if you dont know which char, then you need to try all to find out which one it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you use `std::string`, you can remove a character from a string via its `erase`:

```
std::string A{"AACB"};
std::string copy = A;  // make a copy to keep the original
copy.erase(2);         // erase character at pos 2
std::cout << copy;     // prints AAB
```

If you don't know which character to remove in advance, you can try all characters in a loop and call your function for `X` and the other string `Y` after removing one character, in a loop.